# mysql - using joins to get several informations

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following tables:

```
TABLE article 
article_id
title
article_text
user_id

TABLE tag_article
tag_article_id
tag_id
article_id

TABLE tag
tag_id
tag

TABLE user
user_id
```

What I want is to search all articles that have a string in the title OR in the content OR on a tag.

My current query is the following:

```
SELECT article.article_id,article.title,user.user_id,article.article_text,
FROM tag,user,article
WHERE (article_text LIKE ? OR title LIKE ? OR tag LIKE ?)
AND article.user_id=user.user_id
GROUP BY article.article_id
ORDER BY article_id DESC
```

Comment: What problem are you facing ? Please give a *detailed* explanation.

Comment: When I search for a string, I don't get the desired results. I can't search correctly for a string when I search for tags too since not all articles have tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First i woud advise you to use explcit joins since they are much easier to read and less error prone (like missing the join between article and tag you just did):

Second, unless you have %'s around your strings, you should add them in the query:

```
SELECT a.article_id, a.title, u.user_id, a.article_text,
FROM article a
INNER JOIN user u ON a.user_id = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN tag_article ta ON ta.article_id = a.article_id
LEFT JOIN tag t ON t.tag_id = ta.tag_id 
WHERE a.article_text LIKE '%YOURSTRING%'
  OR a.title LIKE '%YOURSTRING%'
  OR t.tag LIKE '%YOURSTRING%'
GROUP BY a.article_id
ORDER BY a.article_id DESC
```

I'm using LEFT JOIN's, because in the case you have articles without tags, it will still search in the article columns.

Comment: I think there is an error here "LEFT JOIN tag t O t.tag_id = ta.tag_id " can you fix that? I realised that it is "ON" and not "O" :)

Comment: Sure. that's a typo. I keep getting that. gotta fix this N key :p

Comment: Thanks for your GREAT ANSWER! It is indeed correct. Since I'm not used to using JOIN's, I get stuck sometimes :/ I understood those left but not the inner :/ Seems like I need to read more about JOINS and practice :) I just needed to add that extra INNER and LEFT join. Thanks!

Comment: THE INNER JOINS is the explicit version of what you were doing. I used the INNER because an article always has a user who created it. Then used the LEFT JOINS, because an article can have no tags.